# UIViewControllers in uiscrollview calling viewdidappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm adding 5 viewcontrollers to a scrollview with a page control so I can swipe from one viewcontroller to another.

At initialization I'm loading 3 viewcontrollers (left, middle, right)
My problem is that my three viewcontrollers are firing a viewDidAppear but only the center viewController is visible...

Is there a way to avoid the view controllers that aren't visible to call viewdidappear? 
I'm adding my viewcontrollers to my scrollview like so :

```
if (controller != nil){
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
[scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the viewDidAppear method is not related to the visibility of the view, if you get the documentation you will see

> Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

So this method will be called when the view is added to the hierarchy. So the view was loaded, and added to the hierarchy, even in a non visible space of your mainView, it will call viewDidAppear.

To achieve what you want, you should implement the delegate of the scrollView, check the offset, and see in which page you are, then you can call a method on your viewController to do the job you want.